# Image printing not correct aspect ratio?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to print an image however my aspect ration on the A4 papaer is incorrect. I did my search and tried to use the same mm size as the A4 paper but no luck. I'm working on Unity3D 2017.0.3f using .NET 3.5.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, it's in the bottom right and leaving all the space behind. I want it just landscape normal A4 printed.

Here's my code that I'm using to print:

```
public void btnPrint_Click()
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = availablePrinter[0];
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
    pd.OriginAtMargins = true;
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pqr);
    pd.Print();
}

void pqr(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log("PrintingImage");

    System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, e.MarginBounds);
}
```

I tried using a `rect` and making it manually but still didn't work.

Comment: Why are you setting Landscape = true;
if you want in portait?

Comment: Oh sorry, i want it landscape

Comment: Edit my question, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to fix it but changing the Margins

```
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 50, 125);
```